# Jquery/Ajax function does not work when clicking on icon for Django site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I have a script for an `ajax` request using `jquery` which acts to upvote a post on my `django` site. It works fine when I click on the part with the word "upvote", but when I click on my upvote icon, it doesn't register and shows `404 not found` in console. I suspect this has something to do with document and not being able to act on icons. Could anyone help me identify the issue, or know a workaround? Below is my code and picture of error, thanks!

**template.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'main:upvote-post' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- check to see if user has already upvoted post.-->
  <span>
    {% if post.upvoted %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm upvote-btn card-link" id="{{post.id}}" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
      <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-shift" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M7.27 2.047a1 1 0 0 1 1.46 0l6.345 6.77c.6.638.146 1.683-.73 1.683H11.5v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3H1.654C.78 10.5.326 9.455.924 8.816L7.27 2.047zM14.346 9.5L8 2.731 1.654 9.5H4.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h5v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2.846z"
        />
      </svg>

      <span id="total_upvotes_for_{{post.id}}">
        <!-- insert post id into the element here so it could be called in the script -->
        {{ post.total_upvotes}}
      </span>

      Upvotes
    </button>
    {% else %}
  </span>
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".upvote-btn", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '{% url "main:upvote-post" %}',
      data: {
        postid: e.target.value,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
        action: "post",
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("total_upvotes_for_" + e.target.value).innerHTML = json["result"];
        $("#" + e.target.value).toggleClass("btn-success btn-outline-success"); // toggle upvote button using id
        console.log(e.target.value);
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
        console.log(err);
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

[image: picture of error]

Answer (score 0):

Instead to delegate the click event to ".upvote-btn" you can refer to the parent form:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form:has(.upvote-btn)", function (e) {
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form:has(.upvote-btn)", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('button clicked: ok');
    return;
    
    var addr = this.action;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: addr,
        data: {
            postid: e.target.value,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {
            document.getElementById("total_upvotes_for_" + e.target.value).innerHTML = json['result']
            $("#" + e.target.value).toggleClass('btn-success btn-outline-success'); // toggle upvote button using id
            console.log(e.target.value)
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form action="{% url 'main:upvote-post' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- check to see if user has already upvoted post.-->
  <span>
    {% if post.upvoted %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm upvote-btn card-link" id="{{post.id}}" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
        <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-shift" fill="currentColor"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenoddd="M7.27 2.047a1 1 0 0 1 1.46 0l6.345 6.77c.6.638.146 1.683-.73 1.683H11.5v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3H1.654C.78 10.5.326 9.455.924 8.816L7.27 2.047zM14.346 9.5L8 2.731 1.654 9.5H4.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3h5v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2.846z/>
        </svg>

      <span id="total_upvotes_for_{{post.id}}">
        <!-- insert post id into the element here so it could be called in the script -->
        {{ post.total_upvotes}}
      </span>

        Upvotes
    </button>
    {% else %}
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: tried the solution by referring the the parent, now the whole button results in `404`

Comment: 404 means: resouce not found. Please, check the value of form action. Is it correct?  I updated the snippet.

Comment: @cdub can you add the value of "{% url 'main:upvote-post' %}"?

Comment: What should the url be?